# null pointer exception error for a binary search tree

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, binary-search-tree

I am trying to finish up this program but I keep getting this one null pointer exception error and I am unsure on how to get this fixed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
            at BinarySearchTree.insert(BinarySearchTree.java:45)
            at BinarySearchTree.insert(BinarySearchTree.java:37)
            at TreeDemo.main(TreeDemo.java:22)
```

This is line 45:    `int R = root.getString().compareTo(n.getString());`

```
 line 37:    this.insert(root,n);
```

This is my binary search tree class:

```
import java.util.Stack;


    import java.util.Stack;


    public class BinarySearchTree {

    private Node root, n;
    private int size;

       public BinarySearchTree () {
         root = null;
         size = 0;
       }

       public void add (Node b){

          if(root == null){     //tree is empty
             root = b;         
       }else{
         root.add (b);
      }
    }

    public void search(String word){


       Node n=new Node(word);
          this.search(root,n);

    }





       public void insert(String word){
           Node n = new Node(word);
           this.insert(root,n);
       }





      public void insert(Node start,Node n){
      int R = root.getString().compareTo(n.getString());
      if(R==-1)
      {//before
         if(start.left==null)
         {
            start.left=n;
         }
         else
         {
            insert(start.left,n);
         }  
      }
      else if(R==1)
      {//after
         if(start.right==null)start.right=n;
         else insert(start.right,n);
      }
       else
        {
               start.nodeFreq++;
               //System.out.print(nodeFreq);
        }
     }

      public Node search(Node start, Node n){
       int R = root.getString().compareTo(n.getString());
      if(R==-1)
      {//before
         if(start.left==null)
         {
            return null;
         }
         else
         {
            insert(start.left,n);
         }  
      }
      else if(R==1)
      {//after
         if(start.right==null)return null;
         else insert(start.right,n);
         System.out.println("word found");
      }
      else
      {
               return start;
      }
      return start;
   }

   public void printPreOrder(){
      this.printPreOrder(root);
   }

   public void PreOrder(Node n){
      this.printPreOrder();
   }

   public void printInOrder(){
      this.printInOrder(root);
   }

   public void InOrder(Node n){
      this.printInOrder();
   }

   public void printPostOrder(){
      this.printPostOrder(root);
   }

   public void PostOrder(Node n){
      this.printPostOrder();
   }



   public void printPreOrder(Node root){

      if(root!=null){
         System.out.print(root+ " ");
         printPreOrder(root.leftNode());
         printPreOrder(root.rightNode());
      } 
   }

   public static void printInOrder(Node root){

      if(root != null){
         printInOrder(root.left);
         System.out.print(root + " ");
         printInOrder(root.right);
      }
   }

   public static void printPostOrder(Node root){
      if(root!=null){
         printPostOrder(root.leftNode());
         printPostOrder(root.rightNode());
         System.out.print(root + " ");
      }
   }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insert a node into an empty tree, the `node` is `null`. Besides, I think it should be `int R = start.getString().compareTo(n.getString());` in your code and you should first judge `start != null`.